# How can I access the data in the GitHub graphs section?

Tags: git, github

I would like to access the data from the GitHub graphs section. For example, I am interested in [this data](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/graphs/contributors). Some of this data is accessible through githubarchive.org, but it is not identical - there is information in the GitHub graphs that I want to get at that githubarchive.org cannot help me with (e.g. absolute number of forks or contributors for 2011). Further, it does not seem that I can get this data from the GitHub API - since I only get the most recent number of forks or contributors, not a historical number from, say, March 1st 2011.

So, how can I access the information in the GitHub graphs section?

Comment: Have you tried **asking github**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the data in the github graphs is generated from the commits in the repository.

Clone the repository, and then iterate through each commit grabbing the data you want.